# Do not refresh page if there is error in form validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am submitting form which has multiple field and different set of validation in code igniter. When we click the submit, it redirects and check the validation and return me on different page if any error. I don't want to use jquery or javascript.

**index.php** view file

```
<form id="credit_card_form" method="POST" action="/book/final">
    <input class="some_field" type="text" name="some_text" value="hello" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**validate.php** controller file

```
function final_validate(){
   if(some_text is not good){
       $data['msg'] = "It's not good";
       $view = "index.php";
       $this->load->view($view,$data);
   }
}
```

so if function returns false, page should not be refreshed. It should return message.

Comment: use ajax to submit your phone

Comment: go for client side validation. There is a very good library - https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do any complex input validation without refreshing the page is to use javascript/ajax, if for some reason you don't want to use that there are two options

1. **Use [html attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp) for basic input validation, but I would rather not rely on this**

   ```
    // this will force the user to enter at least 1 character and maximum of 10
    <input class="some_field" type="text" name="some_text" value="hello" required maxlength="10"/>
   ```
2. **Refresh the page but keep any values the user entered and show errors**

   ```
     // show errors if they exist
     <?php if(isset($message)): ?>
          echo 'some error html' . $message. 'some error html';
     <?php endif; ?>
    // show previous value if it exists
   <input class="some_field" type="text" name="some_text" value="<?php $this->input->post('some_text') ? $this->input->post('some_text') : '' ?>" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   ```

   ```
   // backend
   // do this if validation fails
   $this->session->set_flashdata(['message' => 'Invalid data.']);
   ```

Even though you can do things this way I strongly recommend using javascript for client side validation.

Comment: There is ```set_value()``` method in CodeIgniter to keep the data after validation failure. Please check.